# Java-->CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am facing below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\abc\man\b\manu.bat C:\Users\12x\test\testFiles\abc.properties" (in directory "C:\Users\12x\test\testFiles\abc.properties"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048).
```

Please find the code i am using:

```
public class TestProcess {


public TestProcess(Path workPath, Path exe, Path logbackConfig, 
                     Path propertyfile) throws IOException {

    String exeSuffix = "";
    if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
      exeSuffix = ".bat";
    }
    builder = new ProcessBuilder()
            .directory(workPath.toFile())

            .command(workPath.resolve(exe).toAbsolutePath().toString() + exeSuffix+ " " + propertyfile)
            .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
            .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
```

My aim is to run a bat file(which is present in C:\abc\man\b folder) followed by abc.properties(which is in another folder C:\Users\12x\test\testFiles).

In code above, workPath has the value

```
C:\abc\man\b
```

and propertyfile has

```
C:\Users\12x\test\testFiles
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `exec()` a .bat file directly in Windows. You have to interpose `cmd /c`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use the correct syntax: you can not concatenate the program and its arguments in a string, since ProcessBuilder is not a parser.

Instead, build a String named propertyfile_path_string corresponding to the properties file, and replace your line `.command(...)` by this one:

```
.command(workPath.resolve(exe).toAbsolutePath().toString() + exeSuffix, propertyfile_path_string)
```

Comment: I tried this, but got below error:

Comment: The method command(List<String>) in the type ProcessBuilder is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String, Path)

Comment: @sandeepgoyal So use `propertyfile.toString()`.

Comment: yooo...worked....

Comment: I've added "build a String named propertyfile_path_string" in the answer.